# Sql max based on another max

Tags: sql, t-sql

i search the forum and i found questions like this but i cannot understand / adapt the code to my query. Apologise for that.

I was asked to get the last value for the fields YEARCPQTY_0 and YEAISSQTY_0

Fields explanation :
ITMREF_0 : item code    NVARCHAR(20)
STOFCY_0 : Factory code NVARCHAR(5)
FIYNUM_0 : Year         SMALLINT
PERNUM_0 : Month        SMALLINT
PERSTR_0 : Period start date DATETIME
PEREND_0 : Period end date   DATETIME
YEARCPQTY_0 : Warehouse entries current year
YEAISSQTY_0 : Warehouse exits current year

This is a sample of how table looks without any query , so you can understand the structure it have. I filter only one item so the output its more understandable and the factory to the one i need the results (otherwise item number repeats for each factory)

I highlited the result i would want to get which is last one.

[Table output][2]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pnHk.png)

Thanks a lot , and sorry again if its dumb question.

Comment: Please read the first couple of paragraphs in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Take two steps back. Don't tell us the problem you're having with your solution. Tell us the question that you were asked that your data is supposed to answer.

Comment: Hello, thanks both for reply, i edited the question several times, hope i get it clear and right. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get the last entry per item is `MAX OVER`:

```
select *
from
(
  select t.*, max(perstr_0) over (partition by itmref_0) as last_period_start
  from mytable t
) q
where perstr_0 = last_period_start
order by itmref_0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Thorsten ! The last part of the query won't work, it don't recognize the fields. All after the ) where perstr_0 =...

Comment: Oops, I forgot the alias for the subquery. SQL Server requires that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Working like a charm Thorsten. Thanks you very much. I will look into over , and partition to see how it works , you query works but i want to understand it too. Thanks a lot!!